# RethinkDB 2.4.1 windows build

Tags: cygwin, v8, rethinkdb

I'm trying to build the rethinkdb in windows using cygwin. Config runs ok, but making the v8 depedency fails. Anybody more lucky?

> Error: open /cygdrive/c/rtdb/rethinkdb-2.4.1/external/v8_4.7.80.23.fetch-wINBkpwO/depot_tools/cipd_client_version: The system cannot find the path specified..
> Bootstrap from scratch failed, something is seriously broken. Run the following commands to diagnose if this is repeating:
> export CIPD_HTTP_USER_AGENT_PREFIX=depot_tools/364205c70ed16c00802b1c264e88d8e03a0b37ae/manual
> /cygdrive/c/rtdb/rethinkdb-2.4.1/external/v8_4.7.80.23.fetch-wINBkpwO/depot_tools/.cipd_client selfupdate -version-file /cygdrive/c/rtdb/rethinkdb-2.4.1/external/v8_4.7.80.23.fetch-wINBkpwO/depot_tools/cipd_client_version
> /cygdrive/c/rtdb/rethinkdb-2.4.1/external/v8_4.7.80.23.fetch-wINBkpwO/depot_tools/bootstrap_python3: line 32: bootstrap-3.8.0.chromium.8_bin/python3/bin/python3: No such file or directory
> 'ygdrive' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> Blockquote

Comment: Actually, the problem runs deeper. It's not possible to build RethinkDB 2.4.1 presently (see: https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/6814)